# style method does not take object

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to change CSS properties of all div elements where class=item (by accessing the div elements using D3 selectAll()). I am able to change only single property using style() but when I try to pass object to style() nothing happens.
For example this works fine:

```
var myData = [{width: 100, background: '#FF0000'}, {width: 140, background: '#B22222'}]

d3.selectAll('.item').data(myData).style('background',function(d){ return d.background})
```

But, this doesn't:

```
d3.selectAll('.item').style({'background': function(d){ return d.background }, 'width': function(d){return d.width } })
```

I read somewhere that styles() must be used instead of style() when passing an object but even styles() does not work. Here is the codepen link containing the code : 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JEoXOV

Can someone tell me what I am missing out here ?

Comment: Related: [*"D3 v4 - cannot read property text of null"*](/q/38684597)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to d3.js documentation https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_style `selection.style(name,value)` accepts single name-value pairs (value can be a constant or a function accepting d,i,data as usual), but not objects

If you want to set multiple style properties, you need to use multiple style() functions

```
d3.selectAll('.item')
    .style('background', function(d){ return d.background; })
    .style('width', function(d){return d.width; });
```

**EDIT:** Or use the [d3-selection-multi](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi) library as Eric Guan pointed in his answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41474957/79536

Comment: using multiple style() works fine. I will see how d3-selectin-multi can be used to avoid using more than one style. Thank you and God bless you.

Answer (score 2):

Mike Bostock moved stuff around in v4.

https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_style

> For the sake of parsimony, the multi-value methods—where you pass an
>   object to set multiple attributes, styles or properties
>   simultaneously—have been extracted to d3-selection-multi and are no
>   longer part of the default bundle. The multi-value map methods have
>   also been renamed to plural form to reduce overload: selection.attrs,
>   selection.styles and selection.properties.